# How do I store unkown IQueryable Result into a list?

Tags: c#, linq

LINQ works fine as follows.  Query shortened for problem purpose.

```
var query = (
             from p in DBContext.Products
             from pp in DBContext.Pricing
             select new { p,pp }
            )
```

Now lets say I wanted a list of this query so for example:

```
var query = List<IQueryable<dynamic>>(); //this is what I assumed the return type would be but no.
for(int = 0; i<5;i++)
{
    query = (from .... select new {p,pp})
}
```

So what is correct return type for query to store queries?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to override 5times the `query` variable?

Comment: As mentioned the query is just to keep this short, it will change on each iteration.

Comment: Rename `query` to `queryList` and then use `queryList.Add(query)`

Comment: Question still remains what will be type of queryList?

Comment: There is no type you can specify, as anonymous types don't have names.  You'll need to create a named type, such as a struct or class.

Comment: @RoadieRich I was just wondering if there is a way to do without creating strong type.  But I guess creating type is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Because anonymous types have no public name, it isn't possible to statically declare a variable using an anonymous type directly, but you can use type inference and the `var` keyword to have the compiler infer the proper type.

Given some extension methods:

```
public static class ObjectExt {
    public static IQueryable<T> AsIQueryableOfType<T>(this T obj) => default(IQueryable<T>);
    public static List<T> AsListOfType<T>(this T obj) => default(List<T>);
}
```

Then you can declare a `IQueryable<T>` or `List<T>` for any anonymous type by passing in the anonymous type. Since anonymous type properties can't be declared, but just initialized, you must assign an appropriate expression to the properties, I recommend using `default`:

```
var ListOfQueries = new { p = default(Product), pp = default(Pricing) }
                        .AsIQueryableOfType()
                        .AsListOfType();

for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    ListOfQueries.Add(from .... select new {p,pp});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one.

```cs
var linqdata = new List<Tuple<DBContext.Products,DBContext.Pricing>>();
```

Comment: The type above might about anonymous type in c#,you just need a Tuple type collection.

Comment: Using .net framework 4.8 so this does not work for me.

Comment: then try the tuple class.

Comment: I doubt that `DBContext.Products` is a type.